# System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 120

Tags: .net

My code perfectly works on in locahost, after publishing it in IIS server it is throwing the error when it is trying to retrieve from database, please help

```
<add name="NewHireAssetEntities1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot; data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=NewHireAsset;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;user id=sa;password=123;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Please add more information, sample code, which version of technology you use.

Comment: I am using .net and microsoftsql, added the connection string code

Comment: error: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.

Comment: IIS server in another computer, right?

Comment: no same machine

Comment: using Microsoft SQL Server Management studio 18